# What is this yellow light on the side of the 2nd stage nozzle - Shenzhou-11 launch

Tags: engines, exhaust, nozzle, shenzhou

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_March_2F) the single engine on the 2nd stage is a [YF-20 series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YF-20) engine.

What is causing the faint yellow light on the side of the nozzle where there is a tube wrapped around it?

[image]

**above:** Screen captures from this [YouTube vide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Jhx4J2j_kw) Arrow is added  indicate the "blob" in question.

[image]

**above:** Screen captures from *this other* [YouTube vide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0vMUO3T0nEg) Similar type of shot. This is the previous launch of Tiangong-2. Seems to be heavily colorized?

Comment: Looks like the joint between the thrust chamber and nozzle extension glowing with heat. But no reference, alas.

Comment: @OrganicMarble In the video (link below screenshot) between 05:55 and 06:05 it seems to be moving around fairly quickly, like exhaust is coming out. (another spot at the extreme right edge of the frame) I don't think hot spots on the nozzle would migrate so rapidly.

Comment: Ah. Not able to watch video at this time, was going by the stills you posted.

Comment: In your second screen shot, the vernier at the left of the frame seems to be burning continuously, so I'm guessing that exhaust-plume interaction between the main engine and the verniers is causing exhaust gas to recirculate up around the nozzle, scorching the metal and liberating some material that burns yellow.